# SQL order by can't find a solution

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm struggling here to do an order by in a query.
Imagine the following result of current query.

> TableA.Id ---- TableB.TagName ---- TableB.TagValue
>   1----------------A---------------------------Customer A 
>   1----------------B---------------------------Contract B
>   1----------------C---------------------------Product Z
>   2----------------A---------------------------Customer B
>   2----------------B---------------------------Contract C
>   2----------------C---------------------------Product Y
>   3----------------A---------------------------Customer C
>   3----------------B---------------------------Contract D
>   3----------------C---------------------------Product X

So the sort is dynamic and can be A, B, C asc or desc (TableB.TagName)
If user selects C ASC as sort, the result should be:

> TableA.Id ---- TableB.TagName ---- TableB.TagValue
>   3----------------A---------------------------Customer C
>   3----------------B---------------------------Contract D
>   3----------------C---------------------------**Product X**
>   2----------------A---------------------------Customer B
>   2----------------B---------------------------Contract C
>   2----------------C---------------------------**Product Y**
>   1----------------A---------------------------Customer A 
>   1----------------B---------------------------Contract B
>   1----------------C---------------------------**Product Z**

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: are you just looking for `order by TableA.Id DESC, TableB.TagName ASC`?  If not, can you explain in a bit more detail what you're looking to achieve?  Using A, B and C in both table names and data is a little confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure what order you are looking for. Is what you are asking for is that all records with Table A ID the same are together, but those groups are ordered by the order of Tag C's value?

Comment: just edited my post to be more clear. No, the idea is not to sort by Id DESC.

Comment: "If user selects C ASC ..." If this query result is used by some kind of report or module, I think your best bet is to manipulate the query sent to SQL from the application, like using IF X then the order by goes like A, etc.

Comment: @DancingFool yes, it's something like that. Similar TableA.Id must be together, and yes if users sort by C then I need to look into TagValue and sort it by C. That's why on my example you see X,Y, Z already ordered. One important note: TagName A,B,C must keep this order - A,B,C. Once again thank you

Comment: What is the relationship between " If user selects C ASC" and the results you show.  I see no obvious connection.

Comment: @GordonLinoff user can select different sorts. He can select A, B or C. If he selects A, the query should sort the content by TagValues with TagName A. On my example, the user selects C and, as you can see, the TagValues for C are sorted alphabetically - X, Y, Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see.

You can use a subquery in the `order by`:

```
select a.id, b.tagname, b.tagvalue,
       max(case when b.tagname = @usertagname then b.tagvalue end) over (partition by a.id) as tagtagvalue
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.tagid = b.tagid
order by tagtagvalue, a.id, b.tagname;
```

To get the descending sort you need a `case` expression in the `order by.

Comment: sorry for my late response. Just need to add one extra field on order by tagtagvalue, a.id, b.tagname. Thank you so much @GordonLinoff.